# How to send memory stream using C# sockets?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm trying to write a code for server-socket, which sending the content of `MemoryStream` over network using `System.Net.Sockets`. I've tried the code below in order to send the content of the memory stream, which isn't null, but the program didn't work. What is the problem with the code and how can I solve it, and if there's another way can you help me?

C# code for client:

```
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = NetStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            return ms;
        }
```

C# code for server:

```
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms = response; //response is also NOT null MemoryStream
            ms.Position = 0;

            int read = 0;
            while ((read = ms.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            ms.Close();
            response.Close();
            stream.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine("DONE.");
```

The results by the debugger: The server continues in the program immediately and the client stucks.

**NOTE**: the code id from this answer: [DataSet & NetworkStream in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197856/dataset-networkstream-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You are disposing the MemoryStream after filling it in the client but before returning it to the caller. You probably want to remove the using statement.

Comment: First, we don't know exactly what your `stream` there in your server and `NetStream` in your client and how they have been created/set up. (it could or could not be related to your problem, who knows). Second, the little code sample of your server here shows some weird things, like you seemingly treating ms and response as different things, like closing them separately (despite them being one and the same thing, because of `ms = response`). Also, what are all those shenanigans with the explicit .Close() calls? If you work with streams, always use `using` instead of explict calls to .Close()...

Comment: First, the memory stream is string or dataset which converted using binary deserialize. Second, I know, I just copied the source code from the question link in my post above, so I don’t know. Can you please help me with writing a properly working code? I just need to fix myself and learn how to do it better. I’m not posting here for just fixing the code, I’m posting to solve the problem.. but thanks anyway..

Comment: On server you're reading from some `response` stream which size is unknown and then send to the client as many bytes as you read from this stream. Say, the `response` contains less than 1024 bytes, on the client side the blocking network `Read` will wait for exactly 1024 bytes which never is going happen in such cases which will cause client to be blocked.

Comment: So I should encode less then 1024 responses using another encoder or using an object which is definitely bigger than 1024

Comment: You should either read exactly as many bytes as you send (which isn't of course good socket programming) or use `DataAvailable` property of `NetworkStream` to read data in smarter manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out by the answers here:

First, Wait For data from the sender (applies to both loops),
and Second, just after reading check if more data available. this way it doesn't wait for nothing.

```
while (true)
{
    if (clientStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                while ((i = clientStream.Read(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesBuffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    memoryStream.Write(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesBuffer.Length);
                    if (clientStream.DataAvailable)
                        continue;
                    else
                        break;

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Received from server {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
    }
```

Thanks!